# How to create Cifar-10 subset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to train a deep neural network using fewer training data samples to reduce the time for testing my code. II wanted to know how to subset the Cifar-10 dataset using Keras TensorFlow.I have the following code which is training for Cifar-10 complete dataset.

```
#load and prepare data
if WhichDataSet == 'CIFAR10':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
else:
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tensorflow.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()
num_classes = np.unique(y_train).shape[0]
K_train = x_train.shape[0]
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
y_train = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Cifar Loader returns tuples of numpy arrays. You can slice them using numpy if you want to have smaller amount of images into your network.

Answer (score 6):

**Create susbset based on labels**

Create a subset of dataset excluding few labels. For example, to create a new train dataset with only first five class labels you can use below code

```
subset_x_train = x_train[np.isin(y_train, [0,1,2,3,4]).flatten()]
subset_y_train = y_train[np.isin(y_train, [0,1,2,3,4]).flatten()]
```

**Create subset irrespective of labels**

To create a 10% subset of train data you can use below code

```
# Shuffle first (optional)
idx = np.arange(len(x_train))
np.random.shuffle(idx)

# get first 10% of data
subset_x_train = x_train[:int(.10*len(idx))]
subset_y_train = y_train[:int(.10*len(idx))]
```

Repeat the same for `x_test` and `y_test` to get a subset of test data.

Comment: How can I change this to take, lets say classes 3, 5, 7 etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the pandas module to create a data frame and sample it accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
(train_images1, train_labels), (test_images1, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images1 / 255.0, test_images1 / 255.0

#creating the validation set from the training set
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(train_images, train_labels)), columns =['Image', 'label']) 
val = df.sample(frac=0.2)
X_train = np.array([ i for i in list(val['Image'])])
y_train = np.array([ [i[0]] for i in list(val['label'])])
```

The line `val = df.sample(frac=0.2)` samples out 0.20 percent of the total data .

You can use `val = df.sample(n=5000)` if you want a specific number of data records, by setting the `n` value accordingly.

You can use `random_state = 0` if you want the same results every time you run the code. eg:

```
val = df.sample(n=5000,random_state = 0)
```